# How can one easily implement the interface of an aggregated object? (language independent)

Tags: c#, java, oop, design-patterns, dry

I have an library with interface which contains substential amount of method declarations:

```
interface ILibInterface
{
    public method1();
    public method2();
    public method3();
    // etc.
}
```

and class that implement this iterface:

```
class LibClass : ILibInterface
{
    public method1(){ /* ... */}
    public method2(){ /* ... */}
    public method3(){ /* ... */}
    // etc.
}
```

Now, I wrote a couple of decorators for the `LibClass`, an example:

```
class MyLibClassDecorator1
    // : ILibInterface <- this is what I want
{
    LibClass backingObject;

    public MyLibClassDecorator1(LibClass obj)
    {
        this.backingObject = obj;
    }

    public LibClass GetBackingObject()
    {
        return this.backingObject;
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve is to be able to use that decorators as `ILibInterface` objects, which means that they all have to implement it. But this is a **lot** of code repetition like:

```
public method1() { return this.backingObject.method1(); }
public method2() { return this.backingObject.method2(); }
// etc.
```

Is there a smart way to implement all methods in the `ILibInterface`, while sticking to the DRY rule?

Note 1: The library is mine, so I can alter both `ILibInterface` and `LibClass`, but I'd rather not, as I am aiming for an answer that would let me to do the same with 3rd party libraries.

Note 2: I appreciate answer in either C#/Java/PHP.

Comment: DI frameworks provide such plumbing - C#/.Net [Unity:Using a Behavior to Add an Interface to an Existing Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178466(v=pandp.30).aspx#sec12).

Comment: Wow, this is a good answer too! Do you by a chance know how it is done internally? Does it use reflection?

Comment: You can check yourself - http://unity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest. I expect reflection + code generation (maybe via `Expression` or manually writing IL).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all most of good design principles are strongly related to the *DRY* rule (see [this article](http://martinfowler.com/ieeeSoftware/repetition.pdf) by Martin Fowler for example). Therefore, if *DRY* is about to be violated then something is possibly wrong with the design. And indeed - the [interface segregation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) and [single responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) principles are probably being violated.

Having said this, if you want to stick with this design, you can use a base class:

```
class MyLibClassDefaultDecoratorBase : ILibInterface
{
    protected LibClass backingObject;

    public MyLibClassDefaultDecoratorBase(LibClass obj)
    {
        this.backingObject = obj;
    }

    // have them all here

    public method1() { return this.backingObject.method1(); }
    public method2() { return this.backingObject.method2(); }
    //...
}
```

And then your subsequent decorators can alter only the methods they want:

```
class MyLibClassSimpleDecorator1 : MyLibClassDefaultDecoratorBase
{
    public MyLibClassSimpleDecorator1(LibClass obj)
        : base(obj)
    {
    }

    public override method1() { /* ... */ }
}
```

Comment: Yep, that sound about right. Thanks. I wrote this _Lib_ back in the time when I had no clue what SOLID is. But suprisingly (for me) only the SRP is violated. The `ILibInterface` is actually a couple of interfaces, which I just merged into one for brevity of the question. I'll have to consider refactoring the lib anyway.